# Valkyrie RCP tutorials and guides

Tags: spring, rcp, spring-rcp

Did anyone hear about Valkyrie RCP, the Spring 3.0 port of the current Spring Rich Client codebase ?

I want to try something with this framework because i'm familiar with Spring, but i didn't find any tutorials about that on the internet, where can I find some docs and guides ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actively maintain Valkyrie RCP here [Valkyrie RPC @ github](https://github.com/cmadsen/Valkyrie-RCP/).

You can find documentation for Valkyrie RPC [here](http://cmadsen.github.com/Valkyrie-RCP/) and there a quite a few demo applications in the repository.

To get started quickly use maven to generate a skeleton project like this:

```
mvn archetype:generate
-DarchetypeGroupId=org.valkyriercp
-DarchetypeArtifactId=valkyrie-rcp-archetype
-DarchetypeVersion=1.1-SNAPSHOT
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the project Valkyrie RCP is dead. But I'm not sure.

In fact there is a fork of this project here: [ndeverge](https://github.com/ndeverge/Valkyrie-RCP).

There is some documentation.

Someone have another news about this project. I am also interested.

Comment: if that project is dead, what are the closest other choices to develop RCP applications ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in rich client apps you might want to have a look at [Eclipse Scout](http://www.eclipse.org/scout/). It is Java/Eclipse based and available under the EPL.

Scout primarily addresses building client server business applications. With its clean separation of the client ui model from the actual ui rendering you have the options to run your app with SWT, Swing, or web application (based on Eclipse RAP).

There is a [video tutorial](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Scout/Overview/Screencasts), [wiki tutorials](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Scout/Tutorial), and a [forum](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=thread&frm_id=174) for questions.

Have fun!